# How to make a specific window tab according to its link in the front of all windows tabs opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 windows tabs opened on my browser, so i want when the user click on the button (closeCurrentPage) my script close the current window tab where the user clicks and focus and make - on the front of all windows tabs opened - the window tab with this specific url:(https//:[www.dzboutik.com](http://www.dzboutik.com)).

Here is my code:

```
<button id="closeCurrentPage">close current tab</button>
<script>  document.getElementById("closeCurrentPage").onclick = function(){
window.close();
// I would like something like this :  window("https//:www.dzboutik.com").focus();
// So how to do that with javascript or jquery if there is no way with javascript?
}
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot do this

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The browser hides what other windows are open from JS for privacy and security reasons